# Using coffin class to set-up page geometry

Tags: geometry, xcoffins

I have a specific page geometry that I would like to create for my odd pages using the coffin class. I have been playing around with it, but I am not understanding the documentation for connecting coffins together. Any help would be great!

Why is my odd page text not staying on the first page?

edited MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}   
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{ifthen,changepage}
\usepackage{nopageno} % supress page number

\usepackage[papersize={8in,8in}, top=1in, textwidth=6in, marginratio=1:1 ]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%  shipout even and odd pages title and figures
            \checkoddpage
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{oddpage}}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameOx}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameEx}}
    }

\NewCoffin\FrameOx
\NewCoffin\FrameOddx
\NewCoffin\FigRT
\NewCoffin\FigRM
\NewCoffin\FigL
\NewCoffin\FigM
\NewCoffin\FigR

\NewCoffin\FrameEx
\NewCoffin\FrameEvenx

%%%%%%%%%   set figures width/height  plus height of text area
\newlength{\imageLMR}
\setlength{\imageLMR}{1in} % height and width of the figures, max =2in <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\imageRM}
\setlength{\imageRM}{1.5in}
\newlength{\imageRT}
\setlength{\imageRT}{2.5in}

\newlength{\textH}
\setlength{\textH}{6in} % height of text area, min =3\imageW  <<<<<<<<<<<<
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameOddx{\textH}{\color{green!10}\rule{\textH}{\textH}}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigRT{\imageRT}{% top right
    \fbox{\includegraphics[height=\imageRT,width=\imageRT]{01}}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigRM{2.8in}{% middle right
    \fbox{\includegraphics[height=\imageRM,width=2.8in]{3-1}}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigL{\imageLMR}{% leftmost bottom
    \fbox{\includegraphics[height=\imageLMR,width=\imageLMR]{1aries}}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigM{\imageLMR}{% midmost bottom
    \fbox{\includegraphics[height=\imageLMR,width=\imageLMR]{Ctetrahedron}}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigR{\imageLMR}{% rightmost bottom
    \fbox{\includegraphics[height=\imageLMR,width=\imageLMR]{1aries}}
}

%%%%**************** V gap in figures
\newlength{\Vgap}
\setlength{\Vgap}{(\textH -\imageLMR-\imageRM-\imageRT)/2}

%%%%%%********************* assembly of odd pages

\JoinCoffins\FrameOddx[r,t]\FigRT[r,t]% top right
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[r,t]\FigRM[r,t](0pt,-\imageRT-\Vgap)

\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[r,b]\FigR[r,b] %bottom row
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[\FigR-l,\FigR-b]\FigM[r,b]
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[\FigM-l,\FigM-b]\FigL[r,b]

\JoinCoffins*\FrameOx[l,t]\FrameOddx[l,t]

%%%%************************

    
\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameEvenx{\textwidth}{\color{white}\rule{\textwidth}{\textH}}

\newlength{\Hoffset}
\setlength{\Hoffset}{\oddsidemargin}


% *************** even pages
%\JoinCoffins*\FrameEvenx[hc, t]\Lyricx[hc,b](0pt,\baselineskip)
\JoinCoffins*\FrameEx[hc,vc]\FrameEvenx[l,t](\Hoffset,-\baselineskip)   
%*********************************************  
    
\hspace{2ex} % H offset
\begin{minipage}{3in-5ex}
\sffamily{\huge I. Fireyes} \\ \textit{Full of light; Reveal the way.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize\textbf{Mercenarium Function:} When you sing I. Fireyes, you may choose and discard any number of cards from your hand (you do not have to discard any if you do not wish to). After this, draw cards from the deck until you are holding the maximum of (5) non-hymn cards.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize If this hymn causes a player to draw the last card in the deck before they are holding (5) non-hymn cards, the game enters singularity (meaning that the deck, hymnal, and discard pile are shuffled together, see \textcolor{red}{“Singularity” p. xx}) and the player then continues to draw from the singularity deck until they are holding 5 cards. After singing this hymn, discard it.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize If the game enters singularity for any other reason, the effect of I. Fireyes becomes “Draw (5) cards.”}
\end{minipage}

\newpage

\begin{minipage}{3in-5ex}
{\footnotesize\textbf{Dragonfruit Meanings:}
\textbf{Authority} / Charge, Attraction, Influence / Patience}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize Fireyes represents the gathering of energy before great movement; the act of preparation, of planning, or of cultivating the skills and resources needed to affect meaningful change in the world. It represents leadership and asks us to reflect on the true nature of power; as well as the responsibility of action that comes to those who have cultivated themselves (to have authority is to have both power and duty). It describes the tendency for power to accumulate: As resources and respect build, so too the creative capacities of its sovereignty. Its alteration suggests that the way to cultivate authority is through patience – though taking the time to wait, to learn, and to listen.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize \textbf{Aces} are \textbf{LEADERS}: “The Adept” archetype; Individuals with material power and sources of inspiration or resentment in those around them. Their influence allows them to affect the world in good and bad ways even through small actions. Their powers are amplified by technology, represented in their illustrations as legendary artifacts.}
\end{minipage}

\newpage

\hspace{8ex} % H offset
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth-16ex}
          \centering
    {\huge \textbf{Lyrics}}

        \vspace{1cm}

\textit{Foreign melodies, who is telling these}\\
\textit{animated, complicated fugues?}\\
\textit{Form a symphony, out of your sympathies,}\\
\textit{if you'd please tell us what we should do.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{Hidden in the deepest forest,}\\
\textit{there's a quiet, constant chorus,}\\
\textit{led by men, with eyes, of fire.}\\
\textit{Their chanting's only getting stronger;}\\
\textit{they'll all burn if they're much longer;}\\
\textit{cast into, the funeral pyre.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{Animosity is unbecoming,}\\
\textit{overwhelmed as you may feel.}\\
\textit{Color crossed with destiny,}\\
\textit{you'll be satisfied with what the light reveals.}\\

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textit{Hidden in the deepest forest,}\\
\textit{there's a quiet, constant chorus}\\
\textit{led by men with eyes of fire,}\\
\textit{as they ignite that funeral pyre.}\\
\textit{Their chanting's only getting stronger.}\\
\textit{They'll all burn if they're much longer,}\\
\textit{but they afford their apathy to}\\
\textit{the fire in their eyes.}\\
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vfill
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

[image: odd page geometry]

Comment: Can anyone help me understand why my coffins are not showing up?

Comment: I think that the error is with the FrameOddx coffin. No matter what I change, all I can see is the text in this coffin. After playing with the size of the text, I still cannot see the other coffins that I am attaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is close of what you have in mind.

After filling the boxes with the content (`\SetVerticalCoffin`)  you start with the joins one by one, compiling each time to see if they align properly. So in the first step you will have only

```
    \JoinCoffins\FrameOddx[r,t]\FigRT[r,t]% top right
    \JoinCoffins*\FrameOx[l,t]\FrameOddx[l,t]  % always the last line
```

The first line joins the top right corner of the top figure with the top right corner of the 6x6in greenish rule that define the text area.

The last line joins the assembly to the collector box that will by typeset by `atbegshi` at shipout.

Then you continue adding the remaining figures one by one.

I recommend you to follow the example of the `xcoffin` manual. It is simple and shows everything you need to know.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt]{article}   
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy tex

\usepackage{ifthen,changepage}
\usepackage{nopageno} % supress page number

\usepackage[papersize={8in,8in},top=1in, textwidth=6in, marginratio=1:1 ]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%  shipout figures of odd pages 
    \checkoddpage
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{oddpage}}{\TypesetCoffin\FrameOx}{}}
}

\NewCoffin\FrameOx
\NewCoffin\FrameOddx
\NewCoffin\FigRT
\NewCoffin\FigRM
\NewCoffin\FigL
\NewCoffin\FigM
\NewCoffin\FigR

%%%%%%%%%   set figures width/height  plus height of text area
\newlength{\imageLMR}
\setlength{\imageLMR}{1in} % height and width of the figures
\newlength{\imageRM}
\setlength{\imageRM}{1.5in}
\newlength{\imageRT}
\setlength{\imageRT}{2.5in}

\newlength{\textH}
\setlength{\textH}{6in} % height & width of text area= 8in-2*1in  <<<<<<<<<<<<
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%********************************************* set  the content of  odd pages  
\SetVerticalCoffin\FrameOddx{\textH}{\color{green!10}\rule{\textH}{\textH}} % change to white in final version
 
\SetVerticalCoffin\FigRT{\imageRT}{% top right
\includegraphics[height=\imageRT,width=\imageRT]{example-image-a}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigRM{2.8in}{% middle right
\includegraphics[height=\imageRM,width=2.8in]{example-image-b}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigL{\imageLMR}{% leftmost bottom
\includegraphics[height=\imageLMR,width=\imageLMR]{example-image-c}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigM{\imageLMR}{% midmost
\includegraphics[height=\imageLMR,width=\imageLMR]{example-grid-100x100pt}
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\FigR{\imageLMR}{% rightmost
\includegraphics[height=\imageLMR,width=\imageLMR]{example-image}
}

%%%%**************  V gap   in figures
\newlength{\Vgap} 
\setlength{\Vgap}{(\textH -\imageLMR-\imageRM-\imageRT)/2} % V offset 2 gaps distributed beteween 3 images

%*********************************************  assembly the content of  odd pages 
\JoinCoffins\FrameOddx[r,t]\FigRT[r,t]% top right
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[r,t]\FigRM[r,t](0pt,-\imageRT-\Vgap)

\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[r,b]\FigR[r,b] %bottom row
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[\FigR-l,\FigR-b]\FigM[r,b]
\JoinCoffins*\FrameOddx[\FigM-l,\FigM-b]\FigL[r,b]

\JoinCoffins*\FrameOx[l,t]\FrameOddx[l,t]  
%*********************************************  

\hspace{2ex} % H offset
\begin{minipage}{3in-5ex}   
\sffamily{\huge I. Fireyes} \\ \textit{Full of light; Reveal the way.} 

\vspace{0.15cm} 

{\footnotesize\textbf{Mercenarium Function:} When you sing the Fireyes hymn, you may select and discard any number of cards from your hand (you do not have to discard any if you do not wish to). After this, draw cards from the deck until you are holding the maximum of (5) non-hymn cards.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize If Fireyes causes a player to draw the last card in the deck before they are holding (5) non-hymn cards, the game enters singularity (meaning that the deck, hymnal, and discard pile are shuffled together, see “Singularity” p. xx) and then continues to draw from the singularity deck until they are holding 5 cards.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize If the game enters singularity for any other reason, the effect of the Fireyes hymn becomes “Draw (5) cards.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize\textbf{Dragonfruit Core Meaning / Secondary Themes / Alteration:}
\textbf{Authority} / Charge, Attraction, Influence / Patience
(color/geometry: Fire \textbf{yellow tetrahedron}) (card value: \textbf{Ace}) (astrological sign: \textbf{Aries})}

9. \kant[9]
\end{minipage}

\newpage

\begin{minipage}{3in-5ex}
{\footnotesize Fireyes represents the gathering of energy before great movement. It symbolizes the act of preparation, of planning, or of cultivating the skills and resources needed to affect meaningful change in the world. It represents leadership and asks us to reflect on the true nature of power.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize Its core meaning (Authority) alludes to the responsibility of action that comes to those who have cultivated greatness within them; to have authority is to have both power and duty. Its secondary themes (Charge, Attraction, and Influence) elicit the image of an individual whose skills, resources, or charisma empowers them to trigger great change in the material world; authority draws people to it, giving the authority figure a great deal of influence on the actions of others. Its alteration (Patience) suggests that the way to cultivate authority is through patience – though taking the time to learn, to work hard, and to listen to others.}

\vspace{0.15cm}

{\footnotesize\textbf{Aces} are \textbf{LEADERS}: “The Adept”. Authority figures. Aces are sources of inspiration or jealousy in those around them. Their influence allows them to affect the world even through small actions. Their powers are amplified by technology, represented in their illustrations as legendary artifacts.}

\end{minipage}

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image: out4]

Comment: Thanks again! When I build your code, everything works great, except my second text box leaks over to the next page. Thoughts?

Comment: Replace the `9. \kant[9]` filling text with your content. For example the next paragraph, `{\footnotesize Fireyes represents the gathering of energy before great movement ...`. The maximum height for all the text is 6in.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your update question. Move text from the second minipage to the first. The maximum height for all the text is 6in. Otherwise the minipage will jump to the next page. The text  {\footnotesize \textbf{Aces} are \textbf{LEADERS}: ` does not fit in the first minipage

Comment: is there a way to donate some rep to you? You have really helped me out a lot on this project.